# string split with expand=True. Can anyone explain what is the meaning?

Tags: python, pandas, string, split, expand

```py
all_data['Title']= all_data['Name'].str.split(', ', expand=True)[1].str.split('.', expand=True)[0]
```

Can anyone explain what is the meaning of this line of code? Especially with the `expand=True` and `[1]` `[0]`.

Comment: That isn't the usual string split method, it's a specific method of whatever kind of object `all_data['Name'].str` returns.  I believe you're working with a Pandas dataframe here, you need to see the Pandas documentation to see what methods its objects define, and what parameters they take.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Pandas it is likely that you know also Jupyter Notebooks.
So, for simplicity and readability let's complete the code you've posted
with some additional information in a Notebook-like format:

````
```python
import pandas as pd

raw_name = ['Bob, Mr. Ross', 'Alice, Mrs. Algae', 'Larry, Mr. lemon', 'John, Mr. Johnson']
all_data = pd.DataFrame({'Name': raw_name})

# This the OP's line
all_data['Title'] = all_data['Name'].str.split(', ', expand=True)[1].str.split('.', expand=True)[0]
    
all_data
````

|  | Name | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bob, Mr. Ross | Mr |
| 1 | Alice, Mrs. Algae | Mrs |
| 2 | Larry, Mr. Lemon | Mr |
| 3 | John, Mr. Johnson | Mr |

Where the `expand=True` renders a set of columns of strings. Therefore, after the first split, you may apply again another `str.split` method since the first split has rendered dataframe of strings as columns. This would have been a little more complicated with a regular split (or `expand=False`) which renders a series of lists.

Better explained with code examples:

```python
all_data['Name'].str.split(', ', expand=False) # or no expand at all
```

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [Bob, Mr. Ross] |
| 1 | [Alice, Mrs. Algae] |
| 2 | [Larry, Mr. Lemon] |
| 3 | [John, Mr. Johnson] |

```python
all_data['Name'].str.split(', ', expand=True)
```

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bob | Mr. Ross |
| 1 | Alice | Mrs. Algae |
| 2 | Larry | Mr. Lemon |
| 3 | John | Mr. Johnson |

```python
all_data['Name'].str.split(', ', expand=True)[1].str.split('.', expand=False)
```

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [Mr, Ross] |
| 1 | [Mrs, Algae] |
| 2 | [Mr, Lemon] |
| 3 | [Mr, Johnson] |

```python
all_data['Name'].str.split(', ', expand=True)[1].str.split('.', expand=True)
```

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Mr | Ross |
| 1 | Mrs | Algae |
| 2 | Mr | Lemon |
| 3 | Mr | Johnson |

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

Comment: The error that keeps popping up is: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here: [pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

> Expand the split strings into separate columns.
>
> If True, return DataFrame/MultiIndex expanding dimensionality.
>
> If False, return Series/Index, containing lists of strings.

```
s = pd.Series(
    [
        "this is a regular sentence",
    ]
)    
s.str.split(expand=True)
```

> 0      1     2        3         4
> this    is     a        regular  sentence